# Azure - multiple role instances stuck in 'waiting for status'

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles

I'm having trouble with a number of role instances refusing to leave the "waiting for status" state. It's the same problem that a user had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058987/azure-deployment-problem-one-instance-of-an-azure-role-starts-the-other-is-wa).

My Azure subscription comes from BizSpark and therefore I don't have the ability to submit a support ticket to get this problem fixed (assuming it is the same problem of a bad node).

Presumably, although my subscription comes from BizSpark, I'm still entitled to a functional service. Could anybody help me come up with a self remedy or a way of contacting support please?

Thanks!

Comment: WTF, I think they let their cert expire. Check out this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/751c85c5-b3b5-43ba-9d5b-770472ad79e1

Comment: See also: [Windows Azure Storage Certificate Expired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033020/windows-azure-storage-certificate-expired), which might be related.

Answer (score 1):

Several Azure services are having problems at the moment, check here first:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that having a Bizspark-based subscription excludes you from buying support. The [support plans](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/plans/) should have something that fits your needs. The cheapest plan that will allow you to submit a support ticket (via the web) is $29 per month. I suggest that Bizspark or not, that you spring for at least the $29, so that you can get attention to your issues.

Comment: Even though I haven't paid for support, I would at the least expect a functioning service. Is this a misguided opinion? I can't afford $29 per month.